# Youtube data v3 api cost in dollars

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I cannot find how much is the Google YouTube data api costs.

1.Is it free and has a limit? Or do I have to pay for the fee?

2.If I have to pay the fee, how much and when do I have to pay?

I just searched on Google developer website, and asked to Google by email but they send me a link but there is no information about payement in dollars.

Comment: [YouTube Data API v3 is free](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) even when requesting extended quota.

Answer (score 0):

The [YouTube Data V3 API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) is completely free. You have a default quota limit (huge for small projects) and you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) how it is consumed based on how you make use of the API.